# How to connect to MariaDB (10.5.8) with MYSQL Workbench as user identified via ed25519?

Tags: mariadb, mysql-workbench, ed25519, mariadb-10.5

I can set MYSQL Workbench to connect to MariaDB with SSL connection as user identified via **mysql_native_password**, but if I set the identification to **ed25519** it fails. Exists any plugin or solution for it? Should I use another free database management software for MariaDB?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL Workbench depends on libmysql, which doesn't provide the ed25519 authentication plugin, since MySQL server doesn't support ed25519 authentication.

As an alternative you can connect via TLS/SSL instead, or try to install the ed25519 client plugin from MariaDB Connector/C (assuming that the authentication api is still the same in MySQL and MariaDB).

Comment: MariaDB and MySQL api are not the same anymore, the ed25519 client installation failed.

Comment: Yes, you're right - recent libmysql version bumped interface version for authentication plugins to 0x0101 due to new async routine in auth plugin interface.